# React native navigation v6 duplicate header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using react native v0.66 and react-navigation v6, I see duplicated headers, but I can customize just the 'second' header, the top header should't appears. I don't know how can I show just one header. Please look the [Screenshot app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L39Pe.png)
I think the code is fine.

Thanks!

**dependencies**

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
const isAuth = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuth);

  return !isAuth ? (
    <Login />
  ) : (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**DrawerNavigator.js**

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="News">
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="News"
        initialParams={{screen: 'Dashboard'}}
        options={{
          drawerLabel: 'Noticias',
          nameIcon: 'news-icon',
        }}
        component={DashboardStackNavigator}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

**DashboardStackNavigator**

```
const DashboardStackNavigator = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
          title: null,
          headerLeft: () => (
            <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: BLACK_BLUE,
            borderBottomColor: GREY,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        }}
        component={Dashboard}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested navigators so you have multiple headers. You can hide second header passing `headerShown: false` or `header: () => null` to `options` props in stack screen. If you want to hide the first header, put one of these to`screenOptions` prop in drawer navigator.